# Is there a way to move the location of ICP private image registry of an installed ICP?

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

I am running low on diskspace on the drive where the ICP private image registry is located.  I know it's possible to specify a location for "/var/lib/registry" using a bind mount BEFORE ICP installation.   Is there a procedure to safely move the location of ICP private image registry on an existing ICP cluster?

Answer (score 1):

How to move /current/directory to another partition/disk

Once you have added extra disk, partitioned it, created the filesystem, and are ready to move /current/directory to it; take the following steps:

Assuming /dev/xvdc11 is the created partition with ext4 file system

```
# create a temp mount point and mount your new partition
mkdir /mnt/dirName
mount /dev/xvdc11 /mnt/dirName

# confirm that it is mounted.
df -h

# copy current directory content to the temp mount point
rsync -aqxP /current/directory/* /mnt/dirName

# use bind mount to set the new location
mount --rbind /mnt/dirName /dirName

# unmount and delete the temp mount point
umount /mnt/dirName
rm -rf /mnt/dirName

# persist this change across system reboots
echo "/dev/xvdc11   /current/directory   ext4   defaults   0   0" >> /etc/fstab
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this activity, please look at for more details on image management:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSBS6K_3.1.2/manage_images/image_manager.html
Also it is possible to complete this task by using the API
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSBS6K_3.1.2/apis/image_management.html

Comment: While relevant links are good to have in an answer, their content can change and as such, it is not good to make answers only containing links. Can you add some examples of specifically how to use the APIs you've linked?